# Working of following R Code ? Explanation required

Tags: r

Can someone explain to me what's happening in this R code? Is it necessary to use `na.rm` in the `mean()` function?

```
datasets$Age = ifelse(is.na(datasets$Age), 
                      ave(datasets$Age, FUN = function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)),
                       datasets$Age)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [format your code appropriately](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/371738).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example.

If there are no NA values in the vector, the mean is calculated correctly. If there are NA values and you dont add `na.rm=TRUE` the mean will be `NA`. To prevent that, you include `na.rm=TRUE`.

```
vec <- c(1,4,3,5,4,2,3,4,5,2,3)
vecNA <- c(1,4,3,5,4,2,3,4,5,2,3, NA)

mean(vec)
```

> [1] 3.272727

```
mean(vecNA)
```

> [1] NA

```
mean(vecNA, na.rm = TRUE)
```

> [1] 3.272727